# Change language of a label while user chooses from a picker

Tags: c#, ios, localization, xamarin.ios

I have simple iPad application that has a Label that says "Welcome to the Application". Underneath the label there is a picker with different languages.

The effect I am trying to implement is that as the user goes through the picker choices, the label text is updated to reflect the current chosen language, in other words, the label text appears in the selected language.

I want to get it to work with just Spanish and French at first and then add additional languages later. I have setup an fr.lproj folder and an es.lproj folder in my solution. These folders have a Localizable.string file that has the translation mapped.

I would use the following method to return the localized string:

```
NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString(myString, null);
```

Here are my questions:
How can i specify which language the user has chosen so that the NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString() method returns the correct value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the following `ExtentionClass`

```
public static class Extention
{
  public static string Translate(this string strName, string locale)
  {
      return NSBundle.FromPath(NSBundle.MainBundle.PathForResource(locale, "lproj")).LocalizedString(strName,"","");
  }  
}
```

and call it like below when need it

```
"This is a test string".Translate("fr"); //for french
"This is a test string".Translate("es"); //for spanish
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i did something like this when providing manual language selection option

*1*. Set selectedLanguage when language is selected from picker

*2*. Use this method instead of NSLocalizeString or #define this method

```
-(NSString*) languageStringForKey:(NSString*)key
    {
        NSString *path;
            //selectedLanguage is assigned while language is chosen from your picker.
        if([self.selectedLanguage isEqualToString:@"french"])
                    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fr" ofType:@"lproj"];
            else //Default is english
                    path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];

        NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];

        NSString* str=[languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:nil];
        return ((str && str.length)?str:key);
    }
```